# How to address the error when knitting R-Markdown to html?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, knitr

Markdown to html, it showed error message "pandoc.exe: r-markdown-temp2.docx: openBinaryFile: permission denied (Permission denied)
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1
Execution halted"
When I tried to install "htmltools" it also shows "Error in install.packages : Updating loaded packages".

How to solve the problem?

Comment: I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53384091/r-markdown-pandoc-document-conversion-failed-with-error-1-after-updating-pandoc) might lead you to the answer. Let me know if it's useful.

Comment: So that my experience can help anyone: I've experienced this, and it was caused by my antivirus silently "protecting" the resulting `.docx` file from `pandoc.exe`. I couldn't figure it out sooner because the antivirus couldn't report before pandoc gives up trying to access the file.

Answer (score 1):

- Check to make sure pandoc is installed, else install with `installr::install.pandoc()`
- Delete or rename previously generated document(s). If you can find that / those document(s), you'll see (that it says) "Read Only", the default MS WORD document load status. Unless that status is removed (by deleting the document, for example, or by clicking on that status bar to change it), you can't have permission to overwrite it.